# augmented sixth chords

Tags: guitar, theory

I recently wrote a song in the key of E major, but I augmented the 6th chord and made it a major, so my progression for the chorus is E major, B major, D major, A major. Is this unusual to do? If not, can you give me other examples of songs this is used in.

Thank you

Comment: If you're in E major, you're not using any kind of 6th. [An augmented 6th is also a very specific idea in music](http://musictheoryblog.blogspot.com/2008/02/augmented-sixth-chords.html) I'm assuming your referring to the D major chord. If so see this question as it's pretty much what you want http://music.stackexchange.com/q/29817/7222.

Comment: To clarify, I think your confusion is that you are interpreting the `D` as a `C#m` raised by a semitone (hence 'augmented'). In reality, the `D` is actually the D# lowered (and converted from diminished to major). Hence, the term is 'flat 7' (bVII), not augmented six. Follow Dom's link for more information.

Comment: @endorph Or at least that's the musical consensus on analysis of this sonority (but that's a discussion for another day...)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't augmented anything.You've used a D chord in its own right. That is not augmenting. Augmenting involves taking certain intervals between two notes only, and stretching them by a semitone.

Take E and B. A perfect fifth. Stretch the B up a semitone, to B# (aka C) and you have an augmented 5th. Take the E down to Eb (note, not D#), and it's an aug. 5th.

Even if you took the C#m up a semitone, as a chord it's minor, so the 'augmented' chord should be Dm. It's not.

The simple explanation comes from use of chords from the *PARALLEL* key. Oft used in pop music, where any chords from the E minor key can be used alongside those of E major.

There are many, many examples in pop music of the last 50 odd years.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you did was not an "augmented sixth chord" (which, as mentioned, is a specific kind of chord that generally comes before V to increase tension), but a borrowed chord from Em (D = bVII). It could also be seen as a modal chord; you're essentially playing with both Ionian mode (standard major scale) and Mixolydian (major scale with a flat seventh).

There's a lot you can do with this trick, including potentially modulating to other keys very smoothly now that you've set up a looser tonality!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the chord on ♭7.  Outside the scale, but so what?  It's very common.  Here's a classic example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your song's chord progression is in essence I-V-bVII-IV  (1-5-b7-4)
Looking at the roots by themselves, they are E, B, D and A.

Interestingly, 
the distance from E to B downward is a perfect 4th.
the distance from D to A downward is guess what?  A perfect 4th too.

It is common in a song to first play 2 different chords, then reuse that same interval between the next 2 chords starting on a different root.  (It doesn't necessarily have to be in that key's scale, as your D shows.)

Another song in E that comes to mind is George Harrison's "Got My Mind Set on You."  It starts with C#m to G#m (its roots are a perfect 4th apart.)  Then it goes from E to B (also a perfect 4th.)

You know, I've been busting my brain thinking I've heard this somewhere before.  At first I wanted to keep going down this perfect 4th road, E to B, D to A, C to G.  Then it hit me . .  .

what if we take your example down to the key of D?
We then have D to A, C to G.
It sounds familiar . . .

Those chords are embedded in that prominent downward riff in Led Zeppelin's "Kashmir."  Part of that is
G to D, F to C,
D to A, C to G ...) (*)

Thanks to you, we can now consider playing it in E.

(*) = the guitar plays these chords, the bass stays constant on D.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers fail to mention where OP went wrong.

OP likely took the 6th scale degree and raised it from C♯ to D, building a major chord from it. Trouble is, that D major chord exists in the parallel minor E minor, so us theorists say that **this is a borrowed chord from E minor** instead of the raised 6th degree's major chord. Since in E minor, it'd D major, we call it that instead of C♯♯ major.

Confusingly, we do do it OP's way for some chords; the Neapolitan 6th chord is the ♭II chord; in E major, that's F. But because the note OP describes is either ♯6 or ♭7, we call it ♭7 instead most of the time.