# In C major, how might the use of A#sus2 → E major be described from a theory standpoint?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, analysis

I have the progression

```
C G Am G D G
```

then

```
C G A#sus2  E F G Am
```

So this is suppose to be in C major from what I know the D is a secondary dominant since it resolves to the G(I suppose),
but the A#sus2 and the E major is strange to me. So whats the theory behind this and how to apply them?

Comment: There are no laws that dictate how chords can be used.

Comment: @MatthewRead It's true that there aren't laws that *dictate* how chords can be used, but why do you think question is based on a premise that there are? He states some terminology that *describes* use of the D - isn't it fair to assume that he wants to know some terminology that could be used to *describe* the A#sus2  -  E? (I do think the question could be clearer - e.g. if it included notation, or a link to a recording - but putting on hold as opinion-based doesn't seem to put us on a path gaining to that clarification)

Comment: That A#sus 2 (probably better called Bbsus2) could be Fsus4, which brings it back into the 'key'.

Comment: @MatthewRead - there are no laws; the OP is asking about theory, of which there's plenty.

Comment: @MatthewRead Sorry for the inconvenience....what I wanted to know  that if there's chord borrowing from a parallel mode or using secondary dominants...to what can we relate the A#sus2 or the E ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do many songs in major keys use a bVII chord?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/29817/why-do-many-songs-in-major-keys-use-a-bvii-chord)

Comment: Apart from the one I would close this as a duplicate of, your question is equivalent to one [asked only three hours earlier](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/57863/using-f-major-chord-on-a-song-in-the-key-of-g)!

Comment: (And: yes, this is quite definitely B♭, unless you have a very specific reason to call it A♯.)

Comment: Though... if you ask specifically about ♭Ⅶ → Ⅲ... then this is not quite a duplicate.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - the A# is a red ferret, apart from which it fits theory better as Fsus4, which actually isn't bVII>III.

Comment: @ Tim why does Fsus4  fits better theoretically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two chords are Bb (bVII) and E (V/vi) in C major, so on the surface that doesn't make much sense, but let's take a detour:

The Neapolitan is the major chord at the bII position in a key, and it's a predominant chord that resolves to the dominant (V). This N - V resolution is very common in minor key classic music. E.g in E minor you might hear F/A - B7 - Em. The verse of [this Schoolhouse Rock tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sMoGY_KL5o) is i - N - V - i.

The relative minor of C is A minor, and it turns out, Bb and E is a fine N - V resolution in A minor! Now in both A minor and C major the E would typically resolve to Am, but V to bVI (E to F) is a very common deceptive cadence.

In general, squeezing in progressions from the relative minor (or other nearby keys) is a great way to spice up major key music.

Comment: That's a great observation, didn't occur to me!

Comment: +1 This is exactly it, Steve! I wonder if you'd be interested in fleshing out this answer a little bit to make it more clear? Showing exactly what the Neapolitan and dominant are, and when they're "in" what key?

Comment: There's something in this, although I don't think it addresses the question fully. The V/vi is all very well, but usually a secondary is followed by the target; not seeing that till 3 chords later.

Comment: I prefer to think of it as a standard modal 'V--VI--VII--I' following the Neapolitan.

Comment: @Richard See if my edit is an improvement

Comment: @ Steve Clay thank you for this amazing explanation,so it's actually a modulation to the relative minor  using the Neapolitan chord of the new mode ? since the progression ends on Am.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a modulation unless you've really shifted the tonal center to A afterwards. The F and G chords don't strongly suggest that, but it depends on your vocal melody.