# Does a I V bVII V (F C Eb C) work? And if so, why?

Tags: chord-progressions

Was wondering if it would work and why.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "work"? It's a pleasant-sounding chord progression; if you can come up with an interesting melody to go with it, I'm sure no one will call the music police on you... so what exactly is the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do many songs in major keys use a bVII chord?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/29817/why-do-many-songs-in-major-keys-use-a-bvii-chord)

Comment: Instead of posing the question, your best answer is to play it several times. If it works for you, then, yes, it 'works'. The why part has an answer already.

Comment: To decide it it would "work", look at other songs and you will find that progression.  Then listen to the songs and get the sound in your head and you will be able to use it for your own music possibly.  Give us more detail such as genre or a particular song to understand more of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Does it work? What does 'work' mean? Were Bach or Mozart to have written a piece using that change of harmony, maybe it wouldn't have 'worked'.

Using it in a piece of modern pop or Blues especially, yes, it will work.

Assuming key F, the E♭ is VII♭7, which is commonplace in a lot of Soul and Blues music. Could be said to be borrowed from the *parallel* key (Fm). But initially, someone used it and it was heard to be acceptable, so it got used again and again.